# Already installed .Net Framework 4.8, but still display 4.7 in Windows Features?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have installed .NET Framework 4.8 then I check Windows Features, it still display as .NET Framework4.7 and under Internet Information Services it also display as ASP.NET 4.7

[image]

How to synchronize here to 4.8？

Comment: This should be considered by design. You should ignore the 4.7 part as only .NET Framework 4.8 is there on this machine.

Comment: As pointed out,  the windows features is only to help you install some things that shipped with windows at time of having purchased your computer.  As such that panel and area has VERY LITTLE  to do with actual software installed on your computer. If you wish to see what's installed on your computer (including what. Net frameworks), and general software then open up control panel and then programs and features. So that panel you are viewing has little reflection as to what software and what versions of. Net you have installed   ---  you can quite much ignore that screen you show here

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Windows, it comes with some specific .Net Framework (for example, 4.7 in your case). The Windows Features UI will only show the version that comes with the operating system, so you shouldn't expect Windows features to change names.

If you have installed .NET Framework 4.8 , you can check registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`. If the Full subkey is missing, then .NET Framework 4.5 or above isn't installed. The Release REG_DWORD value in the registry represents the version of .NET Framework installed.

.NET Framework 4.8 On all other Windows operating systems (including other Windows 10 operating systems): `528049`

If you want to know what all .Net versions are installed in server, please refer this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

[image]

Or you can use the RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription property to query for which .NET implementation and version your app is running on.

Comment: Hi YurongDai, I experience the same issue. I installed dotnet 4.8 on my Windows 2019 server but only 4.7 shows up in regedit.
I use the same offline installer on Windows 2016 servers and I get dotnet 4.8.
It's a very strange behaviour on Windows 2019 servers.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and the issue was caused by corrupted patches.
You can check your system health with `DISM`.

```
# Quick health scan
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

# Advanced health scan
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
```

To resolve any discovered issues you can run:

```
# this command can take a long time -- don't close the terminal
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```